# Can't make bootable USB for release 12.04.1

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to make a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu 12.04.1.

The USB drive created by unetbootin doesn't boot; it results in a `Disk I/O error` message.

In trying to create a bootable USB drive, PenDriveLinux installer reports a syntax error in syslinux and then says that the drive will not be bootable.  And it isn't.  It produces the same "Disk I/O error" message.

Is there some way around this or a fix for it?

---

Thank all of you for your help.  The error I kept getting was this:

An error (1) occurred while executing syslinux.
Your USB drive won't be bootable...

After googling around to find out what error (1) was, I moved from my crufty old XP machine to a newer, cleaner Windows 7 machine, and guess what?  PendriveLinux created a bootable USB drive on the first try.

I am happy now.  :-)

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: It's possible that your USB might be defected?!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows to create the usb stick, try marking the partition as active.
Here is how you do it.
1.press windows key and type diskpart and press enter.A command prompt opens.
2.Type `list disk` and press enter.
3.select the disk by using the command `select disk "diskno"`( without the quotes )where diskno is the appropriate disk number as seen in list disk.
4.select the appropriate partition by using `list partition` and `select partition` commands.
5.After selecting the partition type `active` to mark the partition active.
Then try making the usb stick.

If this doesn't help chek the MD5 sums of the iso you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try different Live USB creating soft:[like this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)